# How to findout Selenium PageLoadTimeout value?

Tags: java, browser, selenium, automation, automated-tests

How do I find out what the default PageLoadTimeout value is? The best I could find was -1, however I'm not sure this is a sufficient answer.

Answer (score 0):

The default page load timeout is "unset", which means "wait forever". The actual value of "unset" may differ based on the combination of the browser implementation and the language binding, but it's usually -1 for being unset. Note that the default value cannot be zero, because it's possible to set the `PageLoadTimeout` to zero to force an immediate return.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Jim! I am trying to temporarily change the value and wanted to reset it to the default, hence the question/confusion that ensued. Do you suppose that this value might change in the near future?

Comment: Check your language bindings' documentation for the correct value to set it back to. For example, in the .NET bindings, `SetScriptTimeout()` takes a `System.TimeSpan` structure, and the documentation says to pass in `TimeSpan.MinValue` to have the timeout wait indefinitely.